# Best way to display "Recursive Comments" in android?

Tags: android, json, recursion, gson, reddit

I am creating a Reddit app for practice that uses GSON objects created from getting the Reddit JSON file.  For the comments each comment item has replies which are made of more comment items.  I am trying to figure out the best way to display these that it makes logical sense what is a replay to what.  I thought maybe having a list with a custom adapter, and for each of those items they have a listview that has the next level of comments and so on.  To keep things from getting squished I thought maybe I only go so many items deep and only display comments above a threshold of up votes. Has anyone ever done something similair to this and if so what is a good way to go about it.

Thank

Comment: AFAIK, there are existing Reddit apps for Android. Have you reviewed them to see how they approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library [AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView), but I'm not sure if this is good solution from UX point of view. Personally I prefer to use single `ListView` and load new fragment with underlying list of data. [BreadCrumbs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.html) may be a good addition to that practice to indicate comments level.

Comment: Note that `FragmentBreadCrumbs` was deprecated in API Level 21 and is no longer being actively maintained by Google.

Comment: I really like the AndroidTreeView Look and feel, I am going to give that a try.  Thank you very much.